# Submit an inputs value via ajax on enter press

Tags: jquery

How can I submit a pure inputs value using the enter key? I only have an input field like this and nothing more. The idea is to submit the value in it using ajax when a user hits enter.

`<input class="input-xxlarge search" type="search" name="search" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search for recipes">`

```
$('.search').submit(function(event){
console.log('Ok');

    var $this = $(this);
    var query = $this.('.search').val();

    if(query.length >= 2 || query.lenght <=24) {
         console.log(query);
    } else {
      // Do not submit the form
      event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I'm having problems getting the thing to submit on enter and getting it's value. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't use a form?

I suggest you to put it inside one and append the submit event to it instead of your input.

```
<form action="#" id="your-form">
    <input class="input-xxlarge search" type="search" name="search" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search for recipes">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#your-form').submit(function(e) {
    var val = $('.search').val();
    /* your code here */
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mSXk9/

Comment: I'm avoiding using a form due to css issues.

Answer (score 3):

Forms have `submit` events, inputs don't. Use the `keyup` event instead to trigger your AJAX request:

```
$('.search').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.which === 13) {
        // enter key pressed
        var value = this.value; // this is the inputs value
        $.ajax({
            url: 'your-url',
            data: {
                search: value
            },
            // more options
        }).done(function(response) {
            // do something with the response
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be more precisely.. I'm not sure what you want to do there. 
But maybe this helps you a little bit:

```
<input onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13){YourSearchFunction();return false;}">
```

The keyCode 13 should be the "Enter" Key.